# How to query an API from URL parameters

Tags: php, mysql, json, api

I'm attempting to create an API.. Currently displaying the JSON which I can use in an application.  I i'm trying to query the JSON using url parameters, but I'm a little unsure on what the best approach is.

current url:

```
api/json.php
```

what i am trying to achieve

```
 api/json.php?id=ronnie
```

display all results where id is equal to the parameters defined in the URL

current php for displaying JSON:

```
<?php

 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
include 'connect.php';

if(!$con){ 
die('Could not connect: '.mysqli_error()); 
} 

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM airQual ORDER BY DATE(subDate), subTime DESC"); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
$output[]=$row; } 


$data = array('boards' => $output);
echo(json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)); 

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: add WHERE clause to your sql string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first take the parameter from URL in a variable. You can do it like below:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Once you get the value in `$id` then you can pass it to your query like below:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM airQual WHERE id = '"$id"' ORDER BY DATE(subDate), subTime DESC");
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the URL parameters like this:

> $id = $_GET['id'];